# Jquery get from children

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to get a url from a children classs.

```
<div class="div1">
   <h1 class="class2">
     <a href ="www.helloword.com/id2">hello user2</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Basically I want to use jquery to get the url and then assign it to  `div1` when someone clicks on div1 it will take you to the same page as if you were to click on the word `hello user2`

I have try

```
$(function() {
           $(".div1").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).children('.class2 a').find(".div1").attr('href'); 
             console.log(url); 
    });

    });
```

But this coming up on chrome as `undefined`.

what have I done wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$(function() {
  $('.div1').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).find('.class2 a').attr('href'); 
    console.log(url); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi hsz, `a` wouldnt work because its giving another link. `div1` as other divs inside of it but they they only 2 url links I am only interested in the link in `class2`

Comment: @SarahJames Look at my edit. You can specify element with `.class2 a` selector.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use children(), only find() will work:

```
$(function() {
           $(".div1").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).find('.class2 a').attr('href'); 
             console.log(url); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You added one extra call to find( ".div1" ), it should be

```
var url = $(this).children('.class2 a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to find `div1` in `a` tag. Also, `event.preventDefault()` is not required for `div`, as there is no default action associated with it.

```
var url = $(this).children('.class2 a').attr('href');
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('.div1').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).find('.class2 a').attr('href');
    $(this).append('<p>'+url+'</p>'); 
  });
});
```

Basically if you wanted to show it in the div. Or something similar, however you want to display it.